# Set Focus to TextInput on TouchableHighlight onPress React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get focus to a TextInput on TouchableHighlight onPress method. But this gives me the following error.

> undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   this.refs.TotalInputField.focus')

My code is a follows.

```
setCustomTotalAmount(value) {
        LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
        this.setState({
            customTextValue: true
        });
        this.refs.TotalInputField.focus();
},

renderTotalAmountInModal() {
        if (this.state.customTextValue) {
            return (
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.totalTextInput}
                    ref='TotalInputField'
                    returnKeyType='done'
                    onChangeText={(totalAmount) => this.setCustomTotalValue(totalAmount)}
                    keyboardType='numeric'
                    defaultValue={this.state.totalAmount}
                />
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <Text style={styles.totalAreaText}>{this.props.symbol}{(this.state.totalAmount).toFixed(2)}</Text>
            );
        }
},

render(){
    return(
            <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
                                style={styles.customTotalButtonBorder}
                                onPress={this.setCustomTotalAmount.bind(this, true)}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonBorderText}>Set a custom total/Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
    )
},
```

How to handle this properly? TIA.

Comment: Where are you calling your renderTotalAmountInModal function in render? I can't see it anywhere

Comment: @AkshayRao It's in there, didn't add in the code since the render method is too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided by BTM on reactiflux #general chat.

The problem was the component hasn't mounted properly when the ref was called.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if(prevState.customTextValue === false && this.state.customTextValue === true) {
    this.refs.TotalInputField.focus();
  }
}
```

This solved the issue.